# Only first element in namespace returning an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

Any idea why only wrapper would return an array with the intended object? How might I fix this and whats the best way to create a name space like this one?

```
    const bubble = {}    

    bubble.Name = {
      mainDivId: "bubble",
    
      svgId: "bubble-svg",
    
      firstSvgG: "bubble-g-space",
    
      nodeClass: "nodes",
    }
    
    bubble.Element = {
      wrapper: d3.select('#' + bubble.Name.mainDivId),
    
      svgOuter: d3.select('#' + bubble.Name.svgId),
    
      svgInner: d3.select('#' + bubble.Name.firstSvgG),
    
      nodes: d3.selectAll('.' + bubble.Name.nodeClass),
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
const bubble = {}

bubble.Name = {
  baseDivId: "bubble",

  outerSvgId: "bubble-svg",

  innerSvgId: "bubble-g-space",

  nodeClass: "nodes",
}

bubble.Element = new function() {
  this.wrapper = () => {
    return d3.select('#' + bubble.Name.baseDivId);
  }

  this.svgOuter = () => {
    return d3.select('#' + bubble.Name.outerSvgId);
  }

  this.svgInner = () => {
    return d3.select('#' + bubble.Name.innerSvgId);
  }

  this.nodes = () => {
    return d3.select('#' + bubble.Name.nodeClass);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi stack_me. Can you please add an explanation as to how this solves the problem.  Code only answers tend to be considered low quality.